# Is it possible to know the app which is opened currently?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a beginner in android development. I want to know that is it possible to know the app which is opened currently. I came to know that finding the apps which are running currently through Activity Manager (getRunningTasks()) is now removed from the Android studio. So I want to know is there any other way to know? I just want to know the app which is opened and running currently on the mobile but not the apps running in the background Could somebody please help me in this case?

Comment: Generally speaking, this information is no longer available, for privacy and security reasons. Also, please note that there may be more than one "app which is opened and running currently on the mobile" (split-screen modes in Android 8.0+, dual-screen devices like the Microsoft Surface Duo, freeform multiwindow devices like Chromebooks, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to get event notification. But **AccessibilityService** are specifically for accessibility uses. If you use the service for other purposes, then the application will more likely to be downed/removed for **PlayStore** due to policies. Another viable option is [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager), but with some limitations.

1. [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) is not push event based system. You have to poll in few mills(depends upon the use-case)
2. **Usage Access Permission** grant/deny is not straight forward. You have to start **Setting Activity** with [Settings#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS) action and have to rely on the users understanding of how to grant permission(Since permission list may contain other applications).